# C++ vector iteration code doesn't compile, when vector is passed as reference-to-const

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have the following for loop, that iterates over a vector thats passed-by-reference-to-const

```
void PrintVector(const vector<string>& myVector) {
    for(vector<string>::iterator itr = myVector.begin(); itr != myVector.end(); ++itr)
        someFunctionThatTakesAPassByReferenceToConstParameter(itr);
}
```

The iterator `itr` is passed in as reference-to-const to the function `someFunctionThatTakesAPassByReferenceToConstParameter()`. Thus, it is guaranteed that this function will not change the iterator object. Even though this is guaranteed, why does the code not compile?

EDIT: I know I could use a const_iterator. But I'd like to know why this doesn't compile.

Comment: `::const_iterator`...

Comment: _I know I could use a const_iterator._ It's not you could, you simply have to! And pass `*itr` as Naveen pointed out.

Comment: -1 So many answers, all covering the diverse flaws in the code you have posted, and none deserves to be accepted? I'd say @JohnDibling's answer covers it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So others have pointed out what you have to use, which you seem to be uninterested in. Your other question in a comment was:

> I could use that [i. e. `const_iterator`]. But I'd like to know why this doesn't compile.

The answer is: Because a non-`const` iterator can potentially be modified when dereferenced, and a reference to `const` object doesn't permit that.

Answer (score 5):

> I know I could use a const_iterator. But I'd like to know why this
>   doesn't compile.

The vector class will have two different "begin" function (overloaded on constness). Something like:

```
  const_iterator begin() const { return ...; }
```

and

```
  iterator begin() { return ...; }
```

Since you have a const reference to the vector the former will be called and a const_iterator cannot be converted to a iterator (since the iterator would be able to modify the value "pointed" to).

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
vector<string>::const_iterator itr = myVector.begin();
```

if `myVector` is a const  reference.

Answer (score 2):

use `vector<string>::const_iterator`, that is what `begin()` of a const vector returns.

Comment: I could use that. But I'd like to know why this doesn't compile.

Comment: @user2380088 Because a non-`const` iterator can potentially be modified when dereferenced.

Comment: But the compiler can see that my code doesn't do that. Right?

Comment: @user2380088 But it doesn't care.

Comment: @user2380088, I've edited my answer. The simple answer is that begin() of a const vector just returns a const_iterator, not an iterator and there is no default conversion from iterator to const_iterator.

Comment: @g-makulik: Yes, that is the point. In the end that is why you cannot assign `myvector.begin()` to a `vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: @dhavenith Sorry, I removed my comment. You're absolutely right, and your answer deserves an upvote since it covers that particular flaw in the OP's posted code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include the compiler error, but this seems fairly obvious:

```
someFunctionThatTakesAPassByReferenceToConstParameter(itr);
```

Here, `itr` isn't a `const string&`, but a `vector<string>::iterator`.  You need to dereference the iterator:

```
someFunctionThatTakesAPassByReferenceToConstParameter(*itr);
```

---

This post seems to be psudocode, but as mentioned elsewhere, you also should use `const_iterator` rather than `iterator`:

```
for(vector<string>::const_iterator itr = myVector.begin(); itr != myVector.end(); ++itr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `*itr` to pass the string.